# Ruby on Rails - Postgresql using md5 - Rake aborted! fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, passwords, rake

I'm setting up Postgresql with Rails on Ubuntu and I am getting the error: Rake Aborted! fe_sendauth: no password supplied when running rake commands.

I have the following in my database.yml file:

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: test_database
    pool: 5
    username: postgres
    passsword: <password>
```

I have changed the method of connection in the pg_hba.conf file and restarted the postgresql server however the same error occurs.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I know I can change the method to trust and run the rake commands but I need to use md5 since I want to use thinking sphinx and it doesn't support trust.

I can connect to the database through pgAdmin and in the console with my username and password: psql -U postgres -d test_database.

Am I missing something?

**[EDIT]**
Turns out I cannot speel. I changed 'Passsword' to 'Password' in my database.yml and it works now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed typo, when wanting to use user/password authentication in rails on ubuntu you must change the method access type in the pg_hba.conf of your postgresql installation directory to md5